# Cant change active textbox and set focus after mouse click on it

Tags: vba, textbox, setfocus

After second click on textboxes i cant write nothing after click on button "1". Setfocus is working only at first click ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DYme.jpg)).
Can You help?
Greetings

```
    Private activeTextbox As Control

    Private Sub Textbox_sr_Enter()
    Set activeTextbox = Controls("Textbox_sr")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Not activeTextbox Is Nothing Then
    activeTextbox.Text = activeTextbox.Text & "1"
    activeTextbox.SetFocus
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Set activeTextbox = Controls("TextBox1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    Set activeTextbox = Controls("TextBox2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_Enter()
    Set activeTextbox = Controls("TextBox3")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try moving the text boxes directly on the form. I mean, not each if them on a different frame... Or put all of them on the same frame.

Comment: This is important for me because it is looking very nice. Without it, it will lose nice look. Can't i do it without moving the text boxes?

Comment: I do not know. I only suppose that you don't. It looks to be an Excel bug. Being on a frame, **the text box events stop being triggered**... Not only `Enter` one. That's why the `activeTextbox` control is not updated any more. But if being 'nice' is your target, you can build such a pseudo frame, using two labels. The main one with `BorderStyleSingle` and without caption and the second an ordinary one, keeping only the pseudo frame caption...

Comment: Thanks very much. I was thinking about it one week and it was crazy. I will try with your idea. Greetings! :)